# JavaScript WebSocket Idle time in DevTools timeline

Tags: javascript, websocket, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools, requestanimationframe

I have an application that does the following:

```
WebSocket.onmessage
  put bytes into a queue (Array)

on requestAnimationFrame
  flush queue, rendering the received bytes using canvas/webgl
```

The application receives and plots realtime data. It has a bit of jerk/jank and while profiling my rendering code, I noticed that while the actual rendering seems execute quickly, there are large chunks of idle time during the [`WebSocket.onmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) handler.

[image: idle time is killing my frame-rate]

I tried shrinking the window, mentioned in [Nat Duca's post](https://plus.google.com/+NatDuca/posts/BvMgvdnBvaQ?e=-RedirectToSandbox), to check if I am "GPU bound". But, even with a small window, the timeline gives pretty much the same results.

What I am suspecting now is Garbage Collection. The application reads data from the WebSocket, plots it, then discards it. So to me, it seems unsurprising that I have a saw-tooth memory profile:

[image: saw tooth]

So my question is now two-fold:

1) In the browser, is it even possible to avoid this memory footprint? In other languages, I know I'd be able have a buffer that was allocated once and read from the socket straight into it. But with the WebSocket interface, this doesn't seem possible; I'm getting a newly allocated buffer of bytes that I use briefly and then no longer need.

**Update**:--- Per pherris' suggestion, I removed the WebSocket from the equation, and while I see improvement, the issue still seems to persist. See the screenshots below:

[image: still some white bars]

[image: still some sawtooth]

2) Is this even my main issue? Are there other things in an application like this that I can do to avoid this blocking/idle time?

Comment: "large chunks of time" - looks like 8ms or so of time in the collapsed yellow bar. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the space between the yellow bars, corresponding to the tall white or clear bars in the timeline.

Comment: one idea is to check your render frame rate - you're only going to get 60fps max, but it looks like that should be faster than you are seeing. Another idea network latency... can you take the websocket connection out of it and just use a setInterval? This has the added benefit of playing with either reusing the same bytes or randomly generating bytes in your setInterval to check the impact to GC. Finally, Google says the Timeline will show you "Garbage Collection Pauses" explicitly: hhttps://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling - about 30% of the way down the page.

Comment: great idea. I altered the code, so I read the first set of bytes, closed the connection completely and just kept re-rendering those same bytes over and over. Some improvement, but still the saw-tooth and still some (though  staying under the 16ms, mostly) idle time. So would this suggest that I'm creating to many objects within my rendering loop?

Comment: I might spend some time looking at the canvas element too: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/ - but if you are rendering once every 16ms, you are maxed out at 60 fps.

Comment: You're down to less than 1/2 ms idle time - are you looking for 100% CPU? Did you use a setTimeout? Try a while(true) loop that exits after 10s.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your last comment. Without the WebSocket ( it is closed during the last profiling ), there are still about ~4ms of that idle time during each frame and I still have the saw-tooth memory graph. Maybe I just misunderstand what that white bar means, but it definitely seems to affect my frame rate. What are you saying about setTimeout and a while loop? I am using reqruestAnimationFrame.